# SQL script to run from batch jobs

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, jobs, sqlcmd, batch-processing

I have a sql script that truncates the table and insert into database from a linked server.Since the server is SQL express I will need to use batch jobs to schedule the jobs. Below is a snippet of the batch job that calls the sql script

TRUNCATE TABLE [TABLE1].[dbo].[TableData]

WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:01'

INSERT INTO [TABLE1].[dbo].[TableData]
SELECT *
FROM [SourceServer].[SourceDatabase].[dbo].[VW_View]

The batch jobs works fine if I use the below code but since osql is deprecated I will need to use sqlcmd which is runs in a loop and never stops.

osql -S myserver -E  -i "c:\test.sql" -o "c:\output.txt" --- Runs fine

sqlcmd -S myserver -E  -i "c:\test.sql" ----- Does not work and goes to a loop that does not end.

I will appreciate if someone can provide me the correct syntax for the sqlcmd.

Comment: Note sure if it would help here but make a habit of specifying the `-I` SQLCMD argument for `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`.

Comment: Why `WAITFOR DELAY`? What do you mean a loop...are you continually truncating and reloading the table at a frequent rate?